# Marionette regions and views with existing dom

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a header region where i like to have my navigation available in the initial markup (because of SEO)

```
    <header id="header-region">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>frontpage</li>
            <li>about</li>
            <li>contact</li>
            <li>testing</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

Then i created a Marionette Layout View:

```
var MenuView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({});
var menuView = new MenuView({
    el: '#menu'
}); 

App.headerRegion.attachView(menuView);
```

This works flawless, but when i later change the headerRegion content

```
App.headerRegion.show(anotherView);
```

And then wanna switch back to the original mainView using

```
App.headerRegion.show(menuView);
```

It tries to render the menuView but because it has no "template" it fails, can i somehow reuse the same view instance without re-render it ? Or is the "Marionette way" of doing it to re-initialize a new menuView ? (im just curious if i have a rather complex view that needs to be swapped out quite alot, the view re-render each time could be quite expensive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a region's content is swapped in Marionette the previous view that was displayed in that region will be closed; and you generally want to avoid reusing views that have previously been closed. There is quite a bit of binding (of event and dom component) that goes into inflating a view and you could cause hard to track bugs re-using views because some of those bindings might not happen.

I've ran into a few my self like [Switching views on regions loses the event bindings](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/223).

Comment: Thanks :) since i need to swap my views, and i like my view "el" to be in the initial HTML (for SEO purpose) do you have any suggestions on how i could solve my problem? i could imagine its a quite common issue , one way i could think of would be to "cache" the original DOM node reference and every time i need to rebuild do new MenuView({el: cachedDomNode});

Comment: It might be safer to achieve that using css rather than Regions, have them always be active in the dom but show and hide them using `display: none`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `App.headerRegion.show(anotherView);` will dump the contents of your header region and replace those with the contents of `anotherView`. When you try to revert the region to its previous state by calling `App.headerRegion.show(menuView)`, the markup you were relying on no longer exists.

The Backbone/Marionette way to do this is to use a template. Marionette uses underscore templating by default, so you can just include the following on your page:

```
<script type="text/template" id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>frontpage</li>
        <li>about</li>
        <li>contact</li>
        <li>testing</li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

And then define your `MenuView` as:

```
var menuView = new MenuView({
    template: '#menu'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up what happens when the view gets replaced, the suggestion you mention removes the main menu from the initial HTML of my page, i really like to have it for SEO reasons, do you have any suggestions to solve that?

Comment: In that case, you would need to have it in both places. Are you using any kind of server-side templating? If so, you could save that html as a variable and interpolate it twice on your page.